# CANopenNode uses the difference between dynamic application and static application?

Tags: canopen

I recently used CANopenNode on stm32, and I found that the macro definition of CO_USE_GLOBALS can control the static memory allocation and dynamic memory allocation of the program. What is the difference between these two ways? Which method is generally more stable?

```
/**
 * If macro is defined externally, then global variables for CANopen objects
 * will be used instead of heap. This is possible only if CO_MULTIPLE_OD is not
 * defined.
 */

#ifdef CO_DOXYGEN
#define CO_USE_GLOBALS
#endif
```

CANopenNode uses the difference between dynamic application and static application?(heap or stack)

Comment: Do not use dynamic allocation when you program microcontrollers unless you use mechanisms like memory pools or similar. and you really know what you are doing. #

Answer (score 0):

Do not use dynamic allocation when you program microcontrollers unless you use mechanisms like memory pools or similar. and you really know what you are doing(1).

Use static allocation as it is very unlikely to use multiple dictionaries on uC.

> CANopenNode uses the difference between dynamic application and static
> application?(heap or stack)

Stick to static allocation (read p. (1))

Comment: Thinks! Your answer is helpful.